# How to use COM smart pointer as in-out arguments for calling e.g. library functions

Tags: c++, com, smart-pointers

What is the best way to use CComPtr or _com_ptr smart pointers as in-out arguments?

```
void FunctionPrototype(Test** test) {
    // you can use here test or create a new Test here and assign to test
}

CComPtr<Test> test;
test.CoCreateInstance(..., ..., ...);
test->SetValue(10);
FunctionPrototype(&test); // assertion since test.p is not NULL
```

Answer (score 7):

There is a comment next to the definition of `CComPtr<T>::operator&`:

> The assert on operator& usually indicates a bug.  If this is really
>   what is needed, however, take the address of the p member explicitly.

So call your function using

```
FunctionPrototype(&test.p);
```

Comment: That's true. What would you suggest for other smart pointers like shared_ptr if you need to supply the argument as in-out?

Comment: `shared_ptr` cannot be used for `[in, out]` parameters as the semantic requirements for overwriting the pointer value are not defined. The only reason it works for `_com_ptr` and `CComPtr` is that anyone modifying the pointer object's internal state also performs the necessary `AddRef`/`Release` that the smart pointer cannot do because it is never asked.

Comment: So the responsibility for calling AddRef/Release lies on the FunctionPrototype if you use FunctionPrototype(&test.p), right?

Comment: Exactly. I suggest you read "Essential COM" by Don Box, it explains the concept rather nicely.